# How to list Docker images built using DinD (Docker in Docker)

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I'm using the DinD (Docker in Docker) approach to build some images. My hosting machine has Docker installed:

```bash
$  apt list --installed docker*
Listing... Done
docker-ce-cli/focal,now 5:20.10.22~3-0~ubuntu-focal amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5:24.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal]
docker-ce-rootless-extras/focal,now 5:23.0.3-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5:24.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal]
docker-ce/focal,now 5:23.0.3-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5:24.0.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal]
docker-compose-plugin/focal,now 2.17.2-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.18.1-1~ubuntu.20.04~focal]
docker-scan-plugin/focal,now 0.23.0~ubuntu-focal amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I'm using [docker:20.10.12-dind](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/docker/20.10.12-dind/images/sha256-af0ce9eee4461072754e6f35f18c219ca6981a16c0042c92bbb4823ce753faa2?context=explore) with a host machine directory mounted as `/var/lib/docker` to build a Docker image. After the image is built, how can I get the image information **from the host machine**? `docker images ls -a` in the host machine returns nothing.

Comment: You need to point `$DOCKER_HOST` at the embedded Docker daemon.  It should be very unusual to need a true Docker-in-Docker setup, in part because it leads to confusing issues like this; what led you to this approach, and how are you building the image?

Comment: I have used docker-in-docker regularly and reliably in a specific usage setting where it is "production" yet _never_ built an image that way.  Why do you need to?  Also, I just do `docker image` and filter or `grep` that.  `docker images ls` gets an empty list for me, `docker images | wc -l` gives me north of 100 here...

Comment: I'm exploring BinderHub https://binderhub.readthedocs.io/ and they use Docker-in-Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run docker command from inside the container.

```
docker exec the_container_running_dind docker image ls
```

Comment: After build the image, the container running DinD stop. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve start a new container.

Comment: `the container running DinD stop` The simplest is to start it then. `start a new container` Start the same contianer. One way or the  other, you have to run dockerd. You could get the path to files on host of the container and execute dockerd on the host - but the version difference, it may break.

Comment: You can't usefully directly inspect Docker state through the filesystem; the Docker daemon must be running to use commands like `docker images`.

Comment: Or, you could potentially write your own parser of docker internal state in the storage driver. The https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ and moby source code will be helpful, but that sounds like a lot of work.